Does 1 multiplied by 1 equal 2?
I have seen on online chatter that this subject is open to speculation.
I would like to attempt to resolve this issue.
Will anybody sell me their house if they agree that this equation is true?
If you estimate that your house is worth 200 thousand would you be willing to part with it for 100 thousand as the equation is one times one equals two and you would not suffer any loss.
Am I being simple or is there something complex that I do not understand?
Is social media full of crappie content or not?
If you do not believe me that this absurdity exists look it up for yourself.

Social media is full of crap. Let it stay there.

Ain't that the truth there's a Hollywood actor claiming the above is the truth as some type of metaphysical messiah I saw it and thougt this s is a cock and bull story.Some of these celebrities can be convincing phonies

@8Mad0Manc8 An actor's whole job is literally to be a convincing phony.

Downvoted the question because the bar is too low. These are the fundamental principles of arithmetic. We learn these in elementary school. That somebody can say this on a show and not be politely shown the door, tells you something about that show....

@gs The first instinct I had to your comment was a laugh. Its frightening now though that what you ordinarily would not experience is now a common event. I say that withr an impolitical prejudice.

@Philomath Jesus the current generation would have a difficulty determining the truth of that observation. Its not lowering the bar it suppases the current generation by several bars !!

@8Mad0Manc8 Okay, ha ha, I am a bit out of touch with the current generation! Seems like we're doomed.

@Philomath Your probably therefore have a distinguished position. I see little pride in the product of a generation that's unable to replicate a prior generation. Iam a great uncle,  my nephews are crazy as fu@k lol. God knows what is going to happen when they are my age and are able to determine the future

Terrence Howard wrote:
In the case of 1 x 1 = 1, we have an unfinished equation.
Because we have 2(1)s on one side of the equation and 1(1) on the other side.
I will not stoop down to explain elementary school arithmetic here.
But I think this question deserves a discussion if only to address this race to the bottom that seems to gain currency in the wider media. Other examples are the Moon Hoax and Flat Earth.
However, I don't think this forum is the place for that.

Yeah two zeroes on one side of the equation equals one zero on the other side of the equation. You  infer that two positive factors are equal  to half of the othersides factor if that factor is unique.

No it's not interesting it's bloody simple one multiplies to two and nothing else if one doesn't multiply it stays them same unless it multiplies by a different factor than a previous multiplication. You might think that this equation is elementary but for some these days it is not unfortunately. Basic mathematical arithmetic is now considered a high brow profession judging by the examples of today's work force

And just to be political those that claim that they do not have the privilege of education and believe education is binary lol.

As a point of clarification ...
I watched an interview where an actor makes this claim. His reason, to the extent I could suss out, is that multiplication is (does he make a reference to the Biblia sacra's "go forth and multiply"???) a procedure that increaseth e.g. 2 × 3 = 6, 6 > 3 and 6 > 2. 1 × 1 = 1 doesn't fit this general pattern since the product 1 = the factors 1.
This idea of numbers has illustrious precedence: Pythagoras, no less, didn't consider 1 to be a number for the reason that numbers were, to him, a "multiplicity".
End of transmission.

If any generation I mathematical then it is geometric. One becomes two. Two becomes four etc etc. Bacteria follow this cell division aswell as most elements of life do not one creates another one and both equally create another that leads to four.

@8Mad0Manc8 that could be one way to look at it. 1 × 1 means 1 ONE, just like 1 apple or 1 orange. Nevertheless, if you look at nonprofessional teachers trying to teach basic math operations, you'll see what the actor's getting at.

I think most people get confused when you issue the term of 'times' this and that. Times is a substitute for multiplication. One can multiplicate too two and two can multiplicate too four however you can subtract any singular element of that multiplication and you get odd numbers as o result of that subtraction. One does not multiply to one it multiplys to at least two.
